# Python convert a Tuple to CSV string

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to implement a REST api to returns records from a SQL database in CSV format.  I would like to use the `import csv` to do the conversion and I would like to use a **generator** so that I can stream the results.

This is what I have tried.

```python
def get_data(query) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    with pyodbc.connect(connStr) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            while 1:
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                if not row: break
                data = io.StringIO()
                csv.writer(data).writerow(row)
                yield data.getvalue()
```

This works, but I don't like it. It seems too verbose and it creates so many temporary StringIO and writer objects!!  Please tell me a better way.

**EDIT** in answer to Adrian's second question, I am calling `get_data` from a `FastAPI` endpoint, as follows.

```python
@app.get("person/csv")
async def person_csv():
    rows = get_data("SELECT * FROM Person")
    response = StreamingResponse(rows, media_type="text/csv")
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    return response
```

I think this is the only way to return an arbitrary number of records without limitation of memory size.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about creating too many temporary StringIO objects. You could definitely just re-use the `writer` object and create it at the top

Comment: why do you need `io.StringIO()` and `csv.writer` at all here?

Comment: 1) You can iterate over the cursor directly per [pyodbc cursor](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor) so you don't need the `while 1 ... row = cursor.fetchone().  2) What are you going to do with CSV rows?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for the excellent suggestion.  I edited my answer below to use `for row in cursor`.  Regarding (2) i added more detail to the question.

Comment: Oh as an aside, `while 1:` is generally not preferred over `while True: ...` just a stylistic suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose I could reuse the StringIO using a seek...

```
def get_data(query) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    data = io.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    with pyodbc.connect(connStr) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            for row in cursor:
                data.seek(0)
                data.truncate()
                writer.writerow(row)
                yield data.getvalue()
```

Comment: this does work, but honestly, having to deal with the statefulness of the `StringIO` object introduces a way to create bugs if this function gets edited in the future. But this is a valid approach. *however* you should use `data.truncate()`. went ahead and took the liberty of editing it in.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good edit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A short alternative solution would be using [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function which (besides of filepath or file buffer) allows to write an object into *csv* string:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data(query) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    writer = csv.writer(data)
    with pyodbc.connect(connStr) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            for row in cursor:
                yield pd.DataFrame([row], columns=range(len(row)))\
                        .to_csv(index=False, header=False)
```

---

Sample test:

```
row = (" a, b, c", 100.3, "Pd's csv, is", '100%', "here and", 'go. ')
print(pd.DataFrame([row], columns=range(len(row))).to_csv(index=False, header=False))
```

---

```
" a, b, c",100.3,"Pd's csv, is",100%,here and,go.
```